# Dynamically append an element to an object

Tags: jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/LThXc/

```
object =  {}
key = 'jimbo'
$.extend( object, { key : 1 })

console.log( object ); // returned {key: 1}, expected {jimbo: 1}
```

It's strange. The variable is evaluated as a string, and that's used as the named key. I want the key to be called `jimbo`, not `key`.

Comment: You can't use variables as keys **unless** you use bracket notation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what the advantages of $.extend are, but this works:

```
object[key]=1
```

The problem with your example is, as you noticed, {key: 1}, evaluates "key" as a string, not a variable. Similar behavior applies to

```
object.key = 1
```

versus

```
object[key] = 1
```

I've spent more time than I'd like to admit debugging this exact issue in my own code, particularly when I started out with javascript.